# Klein-Gordon field transition amplitude calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

In Peskin QFT, the transition amplitude of a particle propagating from $y$ to $x$ is given as $$D(x-y)=\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_p}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}$$
and when the transition is in the time direction, the calculation is like the image below.
[image]

I'm not able to completely understand its calculation process. So as when the transition is purely spatial,

[image]

Can somebody explain how the calculation is done?

Comment: Please do not post images of math. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please explain what parts of the calculations are unclear to you.

Comment: I'm not clear how the d^3p became dp.

Comment: Use spherical coordinates in momentum space: $d^3p=p^2dp\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: perhaps you wish to withdraw the question?